# How to Test assemble api in JcrPackageManager in Junit test cases

Tags: aem, jcr

I am writing test cases for content backup service in AEM 6.0 using `assemble(JcrPackage pack, ProgressTrackerListener listener)` API in `JcrPackageManager` class. How can I test whether package is assembled or not in my JUnit test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your unit tests are executed in an AEM environment (1) you might check if the package is existing in the expected repository path (`/etc/packages/GROUP/PACKAGE`) and if the size is > 0 (`jcrPackage.getSize()`).

Be aware that this will not work with

```
assemble(JcrPackage pack, ProgressTrackerListener listener, OutputStream out)
```

as the package will not be stored in the repo after the assembly has been done. It will be streamed to the output stream.

(1): https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-testing-tools.html